# echo containing subprocess generates unexpected output

Tags: shell

Whenever running a subshell command as part of the `echo` command, I've noticed the output generates some strange results. While I am completely sure this is simply my lack of knowledge on how the Unix shell works, I would really appreciate some explanation on what is happening behind the scenes and what is the appropriate way of handling this use case?

```bsh
$ cat two
two

$ echo "one $(cat two) three"
threeo
```

I would expect `one two three` as the output

### Update

Apologies about the bad example above as the file `two` was previously created with the output of `curl -I`. Just to keep it in context, below follows a more appropriate example.

```bsh
$ curl -sI https://google.com | grep server | cut -d " " -f 2
gws

$ echo "one $(curl -sI https://google.com | grep server | cut -d " " -f 2) three"
threes
```

above, the expected result would be `one gws three`

Comment: @steeldriver, that's spot on! Even the example is really similar (It's a shame I missed it before posting this question). Thanks a lot for linking this!

Comment: No problem - I happened to recognize the symptoms, that's all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File `two` probably has a carriage return in it.

The output you are seeing appears to be `one two` with  `three` overlaid, so that only the `o` of `two` is visible.

You will probably have to clean up the content of `two` to achieve the desired result.

For example:

```
echo "one $(tr -d '\r' < two) three"
```

Comment: Thanks so much! You are completely right. I will remember to pay attention to carriage return from now on.

Answer (score 0):

It all works just fine here:

```bsh
$ echo -n two > two
$ echo "one $(cat two) three"
one two three
```

What's the output of `ls -l two`?

Comment: Hi, Artem. Sorry you are correct. I have updated the question with a more appropriate example since the contents to `two` was previously generated by the output of `curl -I` so perhaps it could've something to do with it? Please see above.